# Text over image on hover using visibility attribute?

Tags: html, css

Working to add a simple image description/text-box appear over an image when it's hovered.

When I don't worry about the hover and just switch the visibility to visible on my span, it's exactly what I'm looking for.

I would've thought that simply using visibility:hidden and visibility:visible on the hover state would've worked, but it's not coming up.

I think I'm having a positioning problem, but I'm clearly overlooking something and have probably been staring at this for too long.

**Abridged HTML:**

```
<div id="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="full-size-image.jpg"><img src="tumbnail.jpg"/>
        <span class="image-caption">Image Caption Text</span></a>
        </li>

        <li>
        <a href="full-size-image.jpg"><img src="tumbnail.jpg"/>
        <span class="image-caption">Image Caption Text</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Abridged CSS:**

```
#gallery {
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
}
#gallery ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#gallery ul li {
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#gallery ul li span {
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index:3;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
}
#gallery ul li span:hover {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Try to remove `;` after `#gallery ul li span:hover`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the `:hover` on the `li` instead of the `span` and target the `span`

```
#gallery ul li:hover span {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w7q86tyf/)

Also remove the `;` on that hover statement:

```
#gallery ul li span:hover; <---- {
```

Comment: Of course.  I'm hovering the li, not the span.  Thank you.